# Add a spring bean configuration file for spring 4 in Eclipse

Tags: xml, spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javabeans

I want to have an option to create a spring bean configuration XML file in Eclipse like STS. Tried to install Spring IDE Roo support but got errors. I am using Spring tools 4. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Spring Roo is something totally different. Just install and download STS (which basically is Eclipse with plugins).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your comment. As far as I know, STS is no longer compatible with the latest Eclipse versions. I tried to use STS 3.9.18 but in the start-up, for instance,  I got the error "An internal error occurred during: "Loading Spring static imports into Eclipse code assist favourites". 
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/parser/Scanner$AjcClosure1" .What do you think? what is your suggestion? Is it better to use Eclipse with the Spring plugin?

Comment: STS is Eclipse with the Spring plugin from VMWare. It is just pre-installed. Also 4.13 is the newest versions and not 3.9 (so you are behing a couple of versions).

Comment: @M.Deinum that is right, thanks